# How to avoid downtime during MySQL RDS SSL Certs rotation

Tags: ssl, certificate, rds, rotation

If you've received the following email from AWS:
**Update Your Amazon RDS SSL/TLS Certificates by February 5, 2020**,
you probably aware that SSL certs rotation procedure will cause an outage even for Amazon Aurora
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html

[image]

**My question is:**

Is there a way to avoid downtime during MySQL RDS SSL Certs rotation?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid downtime during SSL Certs rotation, you can use the approach described in this issue
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55611/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-upgrade-production-rds-instance/203896#203896

First, you need to temporary launching a Master-Master configuration for your MySQL RDS  database. Then update SSL cert on the new Master and finally gracefully switch application traffic without incurring downtime.

You can also find more ideas on it here:
https://workmarket.tech/rotating-rds-ssl-certificates-without-downtime-acd788a93ce7

I hope it helps.

Comment: I take the logic holds for other type of RDBMS (such as Postgresql)?

Comment: Since Postgres doesn't support M/M out fo the box, I don't think you can easily do it. But I see people posting some solutions: https://resources.2ndquadrant.com/upgrade-Postgresql?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=North+America+-+20151020&utm_term=&hsa_mt=b&hsa_ad=407445639248&hsa_cam=386030289&hsa_grp=87105984956&hsa_acc=8827627379&hsa_ver=3&hsa_src=g&hsa_kw=&hsa_tgt=dsa-437115340933&hsa_net=adwords&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI__jM_rb55gIVCZyzCh0n-wBsEAAYASAAEgKwUPD_BwE. AND https://severalnines.com/database-blog/postgresql-high-availability-master-slave-master-master-architectures

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I am not a DBA by trade, but the second link point to solutions based on pgpool and pgboucer that I have been told might be something to look into for M/M somewhat equivalence.